# Chrome API to handle "onHang" tab event

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webkit, interrupt, v8

On Chrome, when a webpage hangs, Chrome will perform a "Pages Unresponsive" interrupt:

[image]

Are there ways to "hook" into this interrupt handler, such that I can run a custom piece of script when a webpage hangs?

What is needed to achieve this?

Comment: I doubt the unresponsive process can run any new code because the state is caused by JS code and JS engine is single threaded within one tab.

Comment: @wOxxOm, Hmm, are webworkers positioned *within* that single threaded engine too?

Comment: No. Worker process is truly threaded AFAIK. And definitely independent from the page (it doesn't have access to DOM after all). I think an unresponsive worker process won't be reported as an unresponsive tab at all.

Comment: @wOxxOm, I'm trying to get them to do something upon onHang.

Comment: Try opening a port connection from a content script to the background page which adds a listener for the inbound port via port.onDisconnected.addListener which in turn checks chrome.runtime.lastError - it may contain a relevant text.